# PHP Catch exceptions run order

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

I have some try-catch exception and if statements in the code below that I am trying to write.

```
try {
    $user = new User($userId);
    if ($user->getEmailToken() == $emailToken) {
        try {
            $user->setEmailToken('');
            $user->setEmailVerified(1);
            $user->store()
            fMessaging::create('success', 'verify', 'Your email has been verified. Thank you.');
            fURL::redirect('/account/confirm.php');
        } catch (fExpectedException $e) {
            fMessaging::create('errorMessage', 'verify', $e->getMessage());
            fMessaging::create('error', 'verify', "Your email could not be verified at this time, please be sure the link from the email was copied correctly.");
        }
    } else {
        fMessaging::create('errorMessage', 'verify', 'User token does not match.');
        fMessaging::create('error', 'verify', "Your email could not be verified at this time, please be sure the link from the email was copied correctly.");
    }
} catch (fExpectedException $e) {
    fMessaging::create('errorMessage', 'verify', $e->getMessage());
    fMessaging::create('error', 'verify', "Your email could not be verified at this time, please be sure the link from the email was copied correctly.");
}
```

My problem is that when it runs, it is somehow setting the email token value to '' before running the if ($user->getEmailToken() == $emailToken) statement, so it always goes to false.

Actually, somehow not only is it setting that, it is also setting the email verified value to 1 and saving my user in the database. Am I doing something wrong with the way I have the try-catch exceptions laid out?

Comment: Check constructor for User object.

Comment: I can't find anything in the User object or it's parents that would cause this. It seems very strange.

Comment: Alright, so I think I might have found a possible problem. The link to this page is generated and sent via an email to the user. I think my browser is possibly pre-loading the link before I actually manually click it. Is there a way I can make the link only work for an actual user visiting the page?